# withRouter with connect is not working in v5.0.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, preact

Versions -

"react-router": "5.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.0.0"

In my app container component, I am using withRouter to access location and history props. I use it like -

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AppContainerComponent));
```

The result is, I get a blank page. No errors, just a blank page.

If I remove the withRouter HOC, it works.

Also, it used to work in v4.0.0-beta.8.

I import the withRouter as -

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
```

Not sure what the problem is.

Note - I have gone through [this link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md) which talks about how the shouldCOmponentUpdate method does not take into account the context changes (which react-router uses now), and it suggests to wrap the component with 'withRouter' HOC, but it is itself not working for me.

Update -

Following is the route path I am using -

index.js -

```
<Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppContainerComponent />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

appcontainer.component (its redux connected) renders following component -

```
<AppRoutes isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
```

appRoutes.component.ts - This component renders the 'UnauthenticatedRoute' and 'AuthenticatedRoute' custom HOC like -

```
<UnauthenticatedRoute
      path="/"
      exact
      component={SignupComponent}
      isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />

<AuthenticatedRoute
      path="/app"
      exact
      component={AppComponent}
      isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
```

The 'UnauthenticatedRoute' and 'AuthenticatedRoute' HOC will render the passed component if the user has been successfully authenticated, otherwise it will redirect to '/signup' path using react-router's **Redirect** component.

The AppComponent has bunch of routes defined by **Route** component as  -

```
<Route exact 
       path="/path1"
       render={} 
/>
```

Another update -

Came across [this link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md#blocked-updates) which talks exactly about the problem I am facing, but the solution - using withRouter. Maybe I am not importing something from right location? [Something similar here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4676#issuecomment-286114288)

I am using react-router and react-router-dom with [preact (8.4.2)](https://preactjs.com/), [preact-cli (v2.2.1)](https://preactjs.com/guide/progressive-web-apps#preact-cli) and [preact-compact (3.18.4)](https://github.com/developit/preact-compat). I am not sure if this is the root cause? Isn't the react-router supported out of the box for preact?

I have set up [this link](https://github.com/awdhootlele/react-router-4-test/tree/issue_example) to demonstrate the issue.(issue_example branch)

Comment: have you tried `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`?  can you post routes path?

Comment: Yes, I have tried importing it from react-router-dom. Actually I followed this - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter .   I didnt understand about the 'routes path', can you explain it a bit?

Comment: I mean there must be route path defined for this component(may be in App.js or some other file) which specifies component to be rendered like: `<Router><Route path="/:id" component={Child} /></Router>`

Comment: Actually, I am unable to figure out **why** it was working on 4.4.0-beta.8 **but not** in the next version v5.0.0.

Comment: did you check this, seems to be similar: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671

Comment: Yes, gone through it (multiple times actually). It suggests, instead of using withRouter hoc in nested components, use it @ top component and pass the {location,history} down to children via props. The main update to withRouter is to make use of context API introduces in react 16, which is useful if we dont want to pass the {location,history} down each component. But the hoc itself is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping just *AppContainerComponent* with your *withRouter*, like this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(AppContainerComponent));
```

Comment: Nope. This does not work. Actually this link - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter clearly says NOT to use the withRouter hoc like that.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by creating custom withRouter hoc which takes in a Component to render and wraps that component inside a Router component. Router component has the props I need (history, location) and I pass them down to the component I am rendering, eliminating the use of RRD's withRouter completely.

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const withRouter = (ConnectedComponent) => {
  const witRouterComponent = (props) => (
    <Route render={routeProps =>
      <ConnectedComponent {...routeProps} {...props} />} />
  );
  return witRouterComponent;
};

export default withRouter;
```

To use it in (for ex. AppContainerComponent)

```
const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(AppContainerComponent);

export default withRouter(ConnectedComponent);
```

[More on this here.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5345)